# GitHub API-list of collaborates

Tags: javascript, java, rest, api, github-api

Is there any way to find the number of contributors of a project via the GitHub API? this solution don't give me the correct resulte 
https://api.github.com/repos/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/stats/contributors?affiliation=all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below api to get list of contributors

GET /repos/:owner/:repo/stats/contributors

Comment: I use this Api but don't show me the correct result

Comment: You will get a list as a response from this api. From that, you will get what you want.